# Why does my for loop not respect the conditional?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, data-structures, sap-gui

To run a SAP GUI data extraction script, I am comparing the modification time of a file with the current time with the for loop, to find out if the file is update. But the loop is infinite, and is not respecting the conditional of the `for` loop.

I need help with this. I'm using python 3.6x

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
GUIPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui'
SID = '-system=x'
InstanceNo = '-client=x'
User = '-user=x'
Pw = '-pw=x'
Language = '-language=x'
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
cmdString = os.path.join(GUIPath, 'sapshcut.exe') + " " + SID + " " + InstanceNo + " " + User + " " + Pw + " " + Language

base_sap = (r'\\teste.com\JK1\Openshare\Groups\Kb_CDO_Informacoes\Tableau\Pedidos_Ingressados\Files\Teste\base_sap.xlsx')
now  = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()

for f in base_sap:
    while os.stat(f).st_mtime < (now - 1800):
        print('Iniciando atualização da Base de Pedidos do SAP.')
        #inicia o sap logon
        call(cmdString)
        time.sleep(4)
        os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM saplogon.exe')
        call(cmdString)
        time.sleep(10)
        #iniciando a sessão no sap gui
        SapGui = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI").GetScriptingEngine
        session = SapGui.FindById("ses[0]")
        time.sleep(8)
        #sap gui script
        session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize()
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickNode("F00002")
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_001/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0100/ctxtS_VKORG-LOW").text = "BR03"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_001/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0100/ctxtS_VKORG-HIGH").text = "BR04"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_001/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0100/ctxtS_WERKS-LOW").text = "*"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_001/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0100/ctxtS_AUART-LOW").text = "ZOR"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_001/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0100/ctxtS_ERDAT-LOW").text = today
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_001/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0100/ctxtS_ERDAT-HIGH").setFocus()
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_001/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0100/ctxtS_ERDAT-HIGH").caretPosition = 0
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_003").select()
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_003/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0300/ctxtP_UNIT").text = "L"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_003/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0300/ctxtP_UNIT").setFocus()
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_003/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0300/ctxtP_UNIT").caretPosition = 1
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_002").select()
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_002/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0200/ctxtP_VAR").text = "PEDIDOS_INGR"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_002/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0200/txtP_TITLE").text = ""
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_002/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0200/txtP_TITLE").setFocus()
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_MYTABSTRIP/tabpCOMM_002/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_MYTABSTRIP:Z0OTC0718_SALES_ORD_REP:0200/txtP_TITLE").caretPosition = 0
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press()
        #exporta os dados em xlsx via automação pyautogui
        time.sleep(6)
        pyautogui.click(15, 32)
        pyautogui.click(57, 106)
        pyautogui.click(291, 126)
        time.sleep(6)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(14)
        #encerra a aplicação excel
        os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM EXCEL.EXE')
        #encerra a aplicação sap logon
        os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM saplogon.exe')
        #copia o arquivo para o diretório compartilhado
        shutil.move(r"C:\Users\%s\Documents\SAP\export.XLSX"  % os.getlogin(), r"\\teste.com\JK1\Openshare\Groups\Kb_CDO_Informacoes\Tableau\Pedidos_Ingressados\Files\Teste\base_sap.xlsx")
    else:
        print('Base atualizada. Iniciando upload para o Tableau')
```

Comment: That means your condition isn't evaluating to what you think it does. There's never a case where the condition is falsey, but the loop continues.

Comment: Your `while` loop is not inside your `for` loop

Comment: What is supposed to be modifying `f` within the while loop? How is it supposed to reach a state when the condition is false?

Comment: @DanielRoseman if the conditional is true the last line of the script overrides the previous file. Changing the modification time.

Comment: But `base_sap` is a single string. Iterating through a string gives individual characters. What's the point of the for loop at all?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was just about to note that; I believe it's supposed to be a tuple of strings. Gabriel, again, make sure your code above works and reproduces your problem, according to [mcve]. (Removing some irrelevant fluff and making the code runnable by third parties wouldn't hurt either).